# Would isotopes of hydrogen separate in liquid phase?

Tags: thermodynamics, hydrogen, isotopes, liquid-state

According to https://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/volume-to-weight
the difference in density of deuterium/hydrogen in liquid state is 70miligrams/cm^3 vs 169miligrams/cm^3.

Would this be a sufficient difference for them to be separated by gravity? If you could cheaply convert hydrogen to liquid state would this be an effective way to de-tritinate nuclear power station water?

Comment: Good luck separating $\text{HTO}$ from $\text{D}
_2\text{O}$, or $\text{HT}$ from $\text{D}_2$. If you created a plasma, though, such nuclei would differ in their charge to mass ratios.

Comment: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-1978-0068.ch001 is a nice (albeit a bit dated) overview. Graphene may offer an interesting path (https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15215). In any event, while liquid diffusion might offer a path (as for gaseous diffusion for isotope separation), one can't just let a vat sit and gravitationally separate.